# Why does my furnace take 3 or 4 tries to get started?

Tags: furnace

I am having an issue with my Trane XR90 furnace. The problem is that the inducer motor turn on and shuts down for three or four times. After 3 or four times, the furnace kicks on and unit works fine. This started couple of months ago and is not happening all the time, just some times in a day.

I called the service person, he suggested the inducer motor needed to be replaced and he changed it.

After few days the problem came back, so I called the service person again and then he suggested changing the pressure switch. He told me 85% of the issue will correct after changing the pressure switch. I agreed and they replaced the pressure switch.

The furnace ran fine for an additional three days. Then again I am having the same issue.

I am not sure what is going on with my furnace. The unit is 17 years old and the service person suggested to change the unit. I am not sure that is the good suggestion. Any suggestion or answer?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: If you have a high-end electronic / digital thermostat, you might try disconnecting it and calling for heat by twisting wires together to see if the inducer runs steady. Do this several times. It's not impossible for a "smart" thermostat to lose its mind and call for heat for just a moment, then reset itself when its watchdog timer times out. The inducer would likely run for awhile, then shut down.

Comment: I'd agree that after 17 years, it's probably time to strongly consider replacement. We eeked ours out for about 25 years, but we had to have our service tech replace the controller board every time our (root cellar) basement flooded. He'd been telling us for 10 years that it was time for replacement because the control boards were almost impossible to find anymore... 17 years is a decent lifespan.

Answer (score 4):

MTA's comment suggesting to bypass the thermostat is a good one. I've seen one "dumb" thermostat go flaky too. It was in a hobby wood shop. It would give one good long call for heat in the morning, but then through the rest of the day its contacts were intermittent and the furnace wouldn't run properly. It was turned off for the night and a day or two later ran fine again.. for one cycle.

To really run this one down somebody needs to catch the furnace "in the act" with a volt meter. One could measure across R and W wires to see whether the thermostat call for heat has a blip, could measure across the pressure switch wires to see whether that switch might be fluttering, etc.

One other possibility comes to mind: the flame proving sensor. If it is intermittent one can imagine that the furnace would start the inducer, heat the hot surface igniter, open the gas, run just briefly, then shut everything down and try the whole cycle again. The flame sensor is most often a stainless steel rod which you can clean with fine sand paper. Might as well give that a try.

Extending on MTA's suggestion: try a new thermostat. A very simple one can be had for much less than the cost of a technician's service visit. Just connect it to the wires, let it dangle on the wall for a week, and see whether the problem clears up.

Answer (score -6):

> The problem is that the inducer motor turn on and shuts down for three or four times. After 3 or four times, the furnace kicks on and unit works fine.

1. open internet browser
2. go to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)
3. search *furnace keeps turning on and off*
4. watch video such as

- furnace turns on then off after seconds - common causes
- furnace starts then stops - troubleshooting
- top 4 reasons why a gas furnace short cycles
- furnace starting and then stopping solved!

https://ibb.co/xjLKgfQ

Comment: "Go search" is not an appropriate answer here. Nor are link-only answers in case you're inclined to properly link the resources you oddly described directions to up there and leave it at that. Please see [answer].